# Is it possible to reference a field in Django using brackets?

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, model

Hello I am trying to see if there is an ability to reference a model in Django using brackets

```
//model
class User(model.Model):
   firstname = models.charField()

//referencing

    user = User.objects.get(id=1)


   //original reference
    user.firstname = "John"


   // proposed reference
     user["firstname"] = "John"
```

Is this possible or are there any alternatived to the proposed reference

Comment: Why do you want that? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Basically I am sending information from the frontend to the backend and there are multiple different fields that I am sending one by one with each page and I want to be able to save that information with just one function @dirkgroten

Comment: So how would having a subscript notation help? If you are looping through key/values, you can also just use `setattr(user, key, value)` which for `key = 'firstname'` is the same as `user.firstname = value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in your model that then call `getattr(..)` and `setattr(..)`. You can for example monkey patch this in the `Model` class:

```
from django.db.models import Model

Model.__getitem__ = lambda x, y: getattr(x, y)
Model.__setitem__ = lambda x, y, v: setattr(x, y, v)
```

But normally it is *not* a good idea to have two ways to accomplish something. As is specified in the *Zen of Python*:

> *There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it.*

If you want to alter an attribute based on the string that contains the name, you can just implement this with:

```
setattr(user, 'firstname', 'John')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to update an object based on a dictionary of key/value pairs, then you don't need the **subscript** notation:

- Either use `setattr`:

  ```
  setattr(user, key, value)
  ```

  will set the attribute `key` to `value`, so if `key = 'firstname'` it's the same as `user.firstname = value`.
- Or update the object directly in the database. Assuming your dictionary of key/value pairs matches the fields you want to update:

  ```
  User.objects.filter(id=1).update(**kwargs)
  ```

  will directly save the object. If `kwargs` is `{'firstname': 'John'}` for example, it'll just update the firstname. Just be careful that your `filter()` expression matches the correct object you want to update.